# Grouping & data wrangling on certain conditions in a Spark dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below dataframe in spark

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+--------+
|pid      |    tid       |account|date        |depid   |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+--------+
|      153|4512          |  30095|11272020    |       0|
|      153|4512          |  30096|11272020    |      30|
|      145|4513          |  40095|11272020    |       0|
|      135|4512          |  30096|11272020    |       0|
|      153|4512          |  30097|11272020    |       0|
|      145|4513          |  30094|11272020    |       0|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+--------+
```

I need to  group  the records by pid, tid and date so after grouping the dataframe looks like

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
|pid      |    tid       |account|date        |depid    |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
|      153|4512          |  30095|11272020    |       0 |
|      153|4512          |  30096|11272020    |       30|
|      153|4512          |  30097|11272020    |        0|
|      145|4513          |  40095|11272020    |        0|
|      145|4513          |  30094|11272020    |        0|
|      135|4512          |  30096|11272020    |        0|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
```

After grouping ,I need to check if any records in this group has an account in 30095 or 40095 then need to replace all the records in that group whose depId is 0 with first 4 digits of account , the expected outcome is

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
|pid      |    tid       |account|date        |depid    |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
|      153|4512          |  30095|11272020    |    3009 |
|      153|4512          |  30096|11272020    |       30|
|      153|4512          |  30097|11272020    |     3009|
|      145|4513          |  40095|11272020    |     4009|
|      145|4513          |  30094|11272020    |     4009|
|      135|4512          |  30096|11272020    |        0|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
```

I tried the below code but it is not working for me

```
WindowSpec windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("pid","tid","date").orderBy("account");
        Column roworder = rank().over(windowSpec).as("rank");
        Dataset<Row> df1 = df.select(df.col("*"),roworder);


      Dataset<Row> df2 = df1.withColumn("depid1",
                 
                  .when(df1.col("account").equalTo("40095").and(df1.col("depid").equalTo("0")), 4009)
                     .when(df1.col("rank").gt(1).and(df1.col("depid").equalTo("0")), 4009)
                         .when(df1.col("account").equalTo("30095").and(df1.col("depid").equalTo("0")), 3009)
                     .when(df1.col("rank").gt(1).and(df1.col("depid").equalTo("0")), 3009)

                     .otherwise(df1.col("depid"))
          ).orderBy(col("pid").desc()).drop("depid1").withColumnRenamed("sourcedid1","depid")
```

but it is producing the below output as

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
|pid      |    tid       |account|date        |depid    |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
|      153|4512          |  30095|11272020    |    3009 |
|      153|4512          |  30096|11272020    |       30|
|      153|4512          |  30097|11272020    |     4009|
|      145|4513          |  40095|11272020    |     4009|
|      145|4513          |  30094|11272020    |     4009|
|      135|4512          |  30096|11272020    |        0|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+
```

I am not sure what am I doing incorrectly here

Comment: where is the grouping? i see no aggregation? looks like distinct and some post-processing. I do not do java, can do in scala and you can adapt

Comment: What is your solution @thebluephantom

Comment: Sounds like u r just ordering...

Comment: What is partitionby for?

Comment: Ok got it. Will do in scala tomorrow.

Comment: Title is misleading, try and reformulate

Comment: Also example looks incorrect or not well formulated

Comment: But we get it. So will look.

Comment: Ok, your logic is flawed in a general sense.

Comment: Help is on its way tomorrow, it ain so complicated.

Comment: unable to create a cluster on databricks ----

Comment: So can you respond pls?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert to JAVA. I suggest you use the Scala API, it makes life far easier. Also, you may have different data types.

Here is my alternative which I see more as a data analysis task. I added some extra records to demonstrate the point and make more generic and robust. I do not think your approach is sound enough. Anyway, we can all learn.

So, here goes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
///...

// More a data analysys problem.

// 1. Gen sample data.
val df = Seq( ( 153, 4512, "30095", "11272020", 0 ),
              ( 153, 4512, "30096", "11272020", 30 ),
                           ( 153, 4512, "30096", "11272020", 30 ),  // extra record
              ( 145, 4513, "40095", "11272020", 0 ),
                           ( 145, 4513, "40095", "11272020", 0 ),   // extra record
                           ( 145, 4513, "40095", "11272020", 200 ), // extra record
              ( 135, 4512, "30096", "11272020", 0 ),
              ( 153, 4512, "30097", "11272020", 0 ),
              ( 145, 4513, "30094", "11272020", 0 )
).toDF("pid","tid","account","date","depid")
df.show()

// 2. Get the groups with accounts of relevance. Note they may have records not needing to be processed.
val dfg = df.filter(df("account").isin("30095", "40095")).select("pid","tid","date").distinct().toDF("pidg", "tidg", "dateg")
dfg.show()

// 3. Get the data that needs to be processed. Take into account performance.
val dfp = df.as("df").join(dfg.as("dfg"), $"df.pid" === $"dfg.pidg" && $"df.tid" === $"dfg.tidg" && $"df.date" === $"dfg.dateg" && $"df.depid" === 0, "inner")
            .drop("pidg").drop("tidg").drop("dateg")
dfp.show()

// 4. Get records that need not be processed for later UNION operation.
val res1 = df.exceptAll(dfp)
res1.show()

// 5. Process those records needed.
val res2 = dfp.withColumn("depid2", substring(col("account"), 0, 4).cast("int")).drop("depid").toDF("pid","tid","account","date","depid")
res2.show()

// 6. Final result.
val res = res1.union(res2)
res.show()
```

results finally in, in a performant way:

```
+---+----+-------+--------+-----+
|pid| tid|account|    date|depid|
+---+----+-------+--------+-----+
|153|4512|  30096|11272020|   30|
|153|4512|  30096|11272020|   30|
|145|4513|  40095|11272020|  200|
|135|4512|  30096|11272020|    0|
|153|4512|  30095|11272020| 3009|
|145|4513|  40095|11272020| 4009|
|145|4513|  40095|11272020| 4009|
|153|4512|  30097|11272020| 3009|
|145|4513|  30094|11272020| 3009|
+---+----+-------+--------+-----+
```